# How to spawn a background job in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to execute a background job in Python and do not wait or block.

How?
e.g.

```
os.system('my long job')
```

The above will block.  I want to fire and forget.

How can this be done in Python?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look on this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/106351/running-programs-in-the-background-from-terminal
Works as well.

Comment: The subprocess module might be what oyu are looking for https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess